# C# method, automatically filling in the parameter list with the default passing

Tags: c#, methods

I just thought of a feature for Visual studio that would be so cool, that I'm wondering if it already exists. It would be something like hitting Ctrl+tab when you do an open parenthesis after a method, to automatically fill in the passing arguments with whatever they were called in the method... assuming you named things the same way.
Does that exist?

For example, if I had a method:

```
public static void Foo(int a, int b)
{

}
```

And then in another location typed out:

```
Foo(
```

I would like to see it populated with:

```
Foo(a, b)
```

after pressing some keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "fill in the passing arguments with whatever they were called in the method"?

Comment: Autofilling with default values?

Comment: What if you don't have `a` and `b` in the other method, but you have `alpha` and `beta` instead?  Now your code won't compile.

Comment: This is not really a programming question. It's more of a feature request so you'd do much better posting this on a Microsoft forum.. P.S. As a side node, you may wish to look for an extension for Visual Studio

Comment: @Bobson - he is probably referring to a similar feature which exists in Eclipse.

Comment: Yes that will be cool, hate typing the redundant crap over and over

Answer (score 4):

The similiar feature exists in Resharper. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, then choose `Generate argument stubs`. But it will fill it with default values like `foo.Bar(0, 0);`